# Udacity CS101: Not sure if this nested dictionary question is wrong or I'm missing something

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm a super beginner in Python on Udacity CS101. The task was to add an entry `is_noble_gas` to an existing nested dictionary so that it would display `True` or `False` when looked up by brackets.

When I submit [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoYFY.png) code to answer the question, it tells me I'm wrong. Am I overlooking something?

**Here is the quiz question:**

Quiz: Adding Values to Nested Dictionaries

Try your hand at working with nested dictionaries. Add another entry 'is_noble_gas' to each dictionary in the `elements` dictionary. After inserting the new entries you should be able to perform these lookups:

```
>>> print(elements['hydrogen']['is_noble_gas'])
False
>>> print(elements['helium']['is_noble_gas'])
True
```

**And that is my attempt:**

```
elements = { 
   'hydrogen': {'number': 1, 'weight': 1.00794, 'symbol': 'H',
                'is_noble_gas': 'False'}, 
   'helium': {'number': 2, 'weight': 4.002602, 'symbol': 'He',
              'is_noble_gas': 'True'}
}
```

Comment: Copy the actual code into here rather than linking to a screenshot, it's much easier to help if there is code to work with.

Comment: It probably want `True` or `False` as a boolean (without the quotes), not `"True"` and `"False"` as strings.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that was the issue. Duh! thank you

Comment: In addition, I could also imagine that the quiz requires not to change the dictionary itself, but to assign the values to the nested dictionary in an extra statement.

Answer (score 1):

This will be like this

```py
elements = {'hydrogen': {'number': 1, 'weight': 1.00794, 'symbol': 'H'},
            'helium': {'number': 2, 'weight': 4.002602, 'symbol': 'He'}}

elements["hydrogen"]["is_noble_gas"] = False
elements["helium"]["is_noble_gas"] = True
print(elements['hydrogen']['is_noble_gas'])
print(elements['helium']['is_noble_gas'])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend avoiding code-only answers: try to provide some explanation and context too.

Comment: The code above is ok, as expected by the answer. Thanks for helping me too. bye.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't actually do anything wrong. The quiz question wasn't asked very accurately and the tests didn't see the possibility that this question could be solved very similarly.

You only defined the value for `is_noble_gas` as a string. There is nothing wrong with your attempt. The quiz does not really make it clear that a boolean is actually required as the value.

The misunderstanding is that the print command has to use a string representation. It makes sense to use the Boolean value as the value itself, only as a string. This is described for example in [PEP-285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).

Nevertheless, the solution to take a Boolean as value is of course more elegant, because it can only take two values and these should also be `True` and `False`.

In addition, I could also imagine that the quiz requires not to change the dictionary itself, but to assign the values to the nested dictionary in an extra statement.